# XPage Set Property to Repeat Index

Tags: javascript, jsf, lotus-notes, repeat

I have a radiobutton in a repeat control, which is supposed to set a property in the controller to the current repeating element

```
----------------------------------------------
Element1                            SetRadio1
----------------------------------------------
Element2                            SetRadio2
----------------------------------------------
```

and the site controller has a property of type Element. So if SetRadio1 is checked the property in the controller class should be set to Element1. 
How do I use the onclick event (in which I am also using javascript) for this?